# Websocket between two computers on same LAN network

Tags: websocket, lan

Is it possible to open a websocket between two computers that are either on the same WAN network or connected via an ethernet cable (LAN)? If it is, can someone provide with some readings I can do to learn about this?

**EDIT:** added my server code

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');  //web server
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);   //web socket server

// ===============================Serial port setup========================
var serialport = require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var parsers = serialport.parsers;
var openSocket = false;

var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    parser: parsers.readline('\r\n')
});

// ===============================Server Setup===========================
const netPort = 8080;
server.listen(netPort); //start the webserver on port 8080
app.use(express.static('public')); //tell the server that ./public/ contains 
the static webpages
console.log("listening on port: localhost:" + netPort);

// ==============================Sending data======================
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('pi', { status: 'opened' });
    console.log('Socket is open'); // log to console, once serial connection is established
    openSocket = true;
});

port.on('data', function(data) {
    if (openSocket) {
            socket.emit('pi', {value: data}); //send data
    }
});
```

Comment: Sure it's possible... you just write and run a small server application on one of the computers and connect to the server application from the other computer using the correct IP and port number.

Comment: @Myst this is what i was thinking of doing. I'm going to add my server code to the question. Then my question is what do i do on the client side and how do I actually connect the computers into a lan. I was thinking of creating a hotspot on one of the devices or just use an ethernet cable?

Comment: It depends how you set up you LAN / peer network. Essentially you would want to connect to the server using it's computer's IP on the client side. I assume the client would be a browser that uses `socket.io` to communicate with the server, so once you figure out the LAN addressing scheme, you should be set to go. Sometimes you can give names to computers in your LAN, allowing you to connect using a computer name rather than an IP address... but it really depends on your system and configuration.